# Is it easy for professors to get academic versions of software from IBM?

Tags: resource-request

I'm developing a big data algorithms course, and would love to teach students how to use [IBM's InfoSphere streams platform](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/bd-streamsintro/index.html), which I once used years ago. Does anyone have experience reaching out to companies like IBM to request a version for academic purposes? First I'd need a version for me to play with and develop course materials, then maybe one for students (perhaps at a discounted price) to learn during the course. I've poked around IBM's website, but can't find any clear "contact us" email address. Hoping someone here can suggest a way forward. Thanks!

Comment: So you are to teach you pupils to be customers. After Graduation, they won't be able to use the product that they learn, unless them become a customer (Same is true for Microsoft, Apple, Google, but you should consider it anyway).

Comment: Well, I did ask months ago on this platform for a free alternative. But no one was able to come up with one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question to ask on the SIGCSE mailing list. A member there was primarily an educator and now works as a sort of liaison to the SIGCSE community. She will probably respond to such a question.

I suspect that they still have grants available that, with some work on your part, might solve your needs. You might need to write up a research proposal, of course. Easy? Maybe no. Possible? Maybe yes.

Comment: If they count pedagogical research as research then it would be easy. Can you remember which SIGCSE member you're referring to? I'm not a SIGCSE member (I'm a PhD mathematician who teaches CS at my SLAC), so not sure if I can write to the mailing list, but I could write her directly. If you don't want to share in the comments here, you could always email me. My email address is in my profile. Thanks!

Comment: If Prof Havill is still chair of your department, ask him. He is a member and subscribed to the list.

Comment: I'm trying to maintain my anonymity and also not give information without permission. A bit delicate. And I think pedagogical research would be a good possibility.

Comment: He's on sabbatical. I think Tom Bressoud is a SIGCSE member too.

Comment: Actually, if you are teaching CS you should consider joining [SIGCSE](http://sigcse.org/sigcse/membership/join). It is very inexpensive and doesn't require also joining ACM, the parent organization.

Comment: Actually, I think my department got me an ACM membership. I didn't realize SIGCSE was part of ACM. Thanks!

Comment: You do need to join SIGCSE separately, of course, But cheap.